# Determining intersection of spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,-1),(2,3,-1),(3,1,-5)\}$ and $V = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,-3),(3-2,-8),(2,1,-3)\}$. Then what is $U\cap V$?

My attempt: there is little I can do, because I do not know how to calculate intersection. I can determine the span of both, but how to compute intersection.

P.S : please dont reduce it to a linear system to solve and determine, because, it can only work for lower dimensional spaces. I want a general method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine $U_1=U^{\perp}$ and $V_1=V^{\perp}$; then
$$
U\cap V=U_1^\perp\cap V_1^{\perp}=(U_1+V_1)^\perp
$$
Now, using column vectors, $U_1$ is the null space of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
2 & 3 & -1 \\
3 & 1 & -5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A row reduction brings the matrix in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $U_1$ is the span of $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

You find similarly $V_1$. Then you can find a basis for $U_1+V_1$ and determine a basis for its orthogonal complement.

In this case it's much easier, though, because $V$ is quite simple to describe.

Comment: Hello, what do u mean by orthogonal? And orthogonal compliment?

Comment: @Shobhit If you don't know those concepts, I'm afraid you can't get really general methods.

Comment: Are there definitions elementary? Should i wiki it, will i be able to grasp concepts of it? P.S i am an undergraduate ( 2nd year)

Comment: Also, if not the general method, how else can i do it?

Comment: @Shobhit First of all, determine the dimension of the spaces involved, then you'll have a clear idea of what's happening. At least you can easily determine the dimension of $U$, $V$ and $U+V$, so also the dimension of the intersection, via Grassmann's formula. But, in this case, there's not much to do, really: compute the dimensions and you'll see.

Comment: Ok, i will try and let u know. Thank u :)

Comment: I am a fan of your answers Dr. (egreg? I really don't know whether this is your real name). Always enlightening and concise.

Comment: @OpenBall Thanks. No, it's not my real name, but you can easily find it by looking carefully in my profile page.

Comment: Ok i was able to determine the dimensions of U and V as 2,3 respectively. How to determine U+V, and its dimension? Also even after determining the dimension of U $/intersection$ V, i cannot match it with the given options. The given options are a) U, b)V, c) the {0} subspace, d) none. Sorry for bothering you again, these type of questions will be on my test, so little worried.

Comment: @Shobhit Since $\dim V=3$, what's it? And then, what's the intersection?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, since dim is 3 its R^3 and therefore intersection is U. Thank u soooo much :)

Comment: How to determine U+V?

Comment: @Shobhit In this case it's not needed, because of the fact that $V$ is the whole space. In general, you just put together the spanning sets.

Comment: I got the answer, but i was just wondering. "Put together the spanning set", what does it mean?

Comment: @Shobhit If $U=\operatorname{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ and $V=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$, then $U+V=\operatorname{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_m,v_1,\dots,v_n\}$

Comment: Oh ok. Thank u again